# Docker Toolbox на Windows не запускается

Tags: docker

Docker Toolbox выдает ошибку при запуске. Ругается на путь, хотя в папке с проектом есть этот файл

[image: Ошибка Docker Toolbox]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: указан путь из корня файловой системы, вы уверены что ваш проект в контейнере доступен именно из корня?